# MPI_Send(97).: Invalid rank has value 13 but must be nonnegative and less than 0

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

```
MPI_Send(171): MPI_Send(buf=0x7ffd6f5e7ccc, count=1, MPI_INT, dest=13, tag=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPI_Send(97).: Invalid rank has value 13 but must be nonnegative and less than 0
```

What could be causing this? I have no idea how the rank could be nonnegative and less than 0.

Comment: You are probably missing a call to `MPI_Init` somewhere. After proper initialisation, `MPI_COMM_WORLD` simply cannot contain less than one rank.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message "invalid rank...must be...less than 0", it is apparent that you MPI world has 0 process in it. Check how you started the MPI processes, and make sure you've called MPI_Init in all processes with the correct process count.